# Problem creating index with included columns (SQL Server Express)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, devexpress

I am using the Database explorer/designer of Visual C# 2008 Express Edition with SQL Server Express 2008.

I created a table and want to add an index. But the index would exceed 900 bytes. One workaround is to use included columns in an index. Unfortunately, the "Included Columns" property is disabled in the Index designer and I haven't found a way to enable it.

Can someone tell me how to enable the property? Is there another way to add included columns to an index using the designer? Is this feature at all supported by SQL Server Express?

Comment: Pardon my asking, but...  does an index with keys (or even data, i.e. in the sense of covering indexes) in excess of 900 bytes make sense ?  Please provide details about your use case.

Comment: You most definitely doing something wrong. I mean there are very rear cases when you actually need such index. May I ask you describe your table structure and why you need an index.

Comment: @Oleg K, we seem to be thinking alike... Not sure what Sebastien has in mind.

Answer (score 13):

You need to create the index by expanding the table in the explorer, right-clicking the Indexes folder and selecting "Add index...".  Make sure the table designer is closed when you do this

Comment: Nice! I wouln't have thought to try this. The "Design"-commands of foreign keys and check-constraints bring up the same dialog that is used by the table designer, so I would have expected the same for New/Properties on indexes. For some reason there is a much more advanced index-"editor" that only seems to be available through the context-menu...

Comment: I never would've found that on my own.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly supported against express. After a while, you'll find limitations in most of the GUI tools, it's worth learning the actual syntax, and entering commands directly. The syntax for [CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) is easily found on MSDN, and they'll normally describe any edition limitations in the remarks section.

So, for instance, I just ran this against my Express instance, without issues:

```
create table T1 (
    ID int not null,
    Val1 varchar(10) not null
)
go
create unique nonclustered index IX_T1 on T1 (ID) INCLUDE (Val1)
go
```

*Edit* also, as others have mentioned, this is an unusual design. Also, one limitation (and possibly why it was disabled in the GUI), is that you can only INCLUDE columns in nonclustered indexes. A little thought about what they are should reveal why.